# How can I update specific cells in an Excel sheet using Python's openpyxl library based on a pandas dataframe with conditional formatting?

Tags: python, pandas, openxlsx

Can someone provide guidance on how to correctly iterate over the rows in the dataframe and update the corresponding cell in an Excel sheet based on the values of certain columns? Can you please see the sample code and data below and suggest improvements?

**Sample data:**

```
  year            animal      branch  imp   val
0  2021              100           A  True  0.01
1  2021              101           B  True  0.02
2  2022              102           C  False 0.03
3  2022              103           D  True  0.04
```

**The code I'm using:**

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

# Load the Excel file
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(folder+"input.xlsx")

def get_col_number(col, val, year):
    sheet = book[year]
    for column_cell in sheet.iter_cols(1, sheet.max_column):
        if column_cell[0].value == col:
            for cell in column_cell:
                if cell.value == val:
                    return cell

def get_row_number(rw, val, year):
    sheet = book[year]
    for row_cell in sheet.iter_rows(2, sheet.max_row):
        if row_cell[0].value == rw:
            for cell in row_cell:
                if cell.value == val:
                    return cell

# Create a dictionary to map True/False values to color values
color_map = {True: "FFFF00"}

# Iterate over the dataframe rows and update the corresponding cell in the Excel sheet
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    sheet = book[str(row["year"])]
    row_num = get_row_number(row["animal"],row["val"],str(row["year"]))
    col_num = get_col_number(row["bransh"],row["val"],str(row["year"]))

    cell = sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num)
    if row["imp"]:
        #Fill the cell in yellow if data.imp
        cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color=color_map[row["imp"]], end_color=color_map[row["imp"]], fill_type="solid")

# Save the updated Excel file
book.save(folder+"output.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Read excel file in pandas.
2. Transform the received dataframe using the dataframe with the new data.
3. Converted dataframe write in excel file using styles.